# Take the cartesian product of two different sized arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having trouble wrapping my head around how to do this. I could have two arrays that I need to combine:

```
const users = [
    {
        user: 'user_1',
    },
    {
        user: 'user_2',
    },
    {
        user: 'user_3',
    },
    {
        user: 'user_4',
    },
]
```

and

```
const labels = [
    {
        label: 'label_1',
    },
    {
        label: 'label_2',
    },
]
```

After combining them the result should look as such:

```
const result = [
    { user: 'user_1', label: 'label_1' },
    { user: 'user_1', label: 'label_2' },
    { user: 'user_2', label: 'label_1' },
    { user: 'user_2', label: 'label_2' },
    { user: 'user_3', label: 'label_1' },
    { user: 'user_3', label: 'label_2' },
    { user: 'user_4', label: 'label_1' },
    { user: 'user_4', label: 'label_2' },
]
```

However, it could also be the case that `users` looks as such:

```
const users = [
    {
        user: 'user_1',
    },
]
```

and `labels` as such:

```
const labels = [
    {
        label: 'label_1',
    },
    {
        label: 'label_2',
    },
    {
        label: 'label_3',
    },
    {
        label: 'label_4',
    },
]
```

whereas the result should then look as so:

```
const result = [
    { user: 'user_1', label: 'label_1' },
    { user: 'user_1', label: 'label_2' },
    { user: 'user_1', label: 'label_3' },
    { user: 'user_1', label: 'label_4' },
]
```

Please excuse if this is really trivial, have been staring at this for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, you need a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the given arrays.

For this approach, you could take a function which returns the product of the arrays. For another array, you could easily add a new parameterin the call of the function.

```js
const
    cartesian = (...array) => array.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => ({ ...v, ...w }))), [])),  
    users = [{ user: 'user_1' }, {user: 'user_2' }, { user: 'user_3' }, { user: 'user_4' }],
    labels = [{label: 'label_1' }, { label: 'label_2' }],
    result = cartesian(users, labels);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to learn about functional features of javascript

```js
users.map(e => labels.map(g => ({...e, ...g}) )).flat()
```

it iterates through both lists, creates a merged objects, and then since labels.map returns an array, we flatten it (e.g merge with original array)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a nested loop:

```js
const result = [];
for (const {user} of users) {
    for (const {label} of labels) {
        result.push({user, label});
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Or, without destructuring and merging all properties of the objects instead:

```js
const result = [];
for (const user of users) {
    for (const label of labels) {
        result.push({...user, ...label});
    }
}
console.log(result);
```